# D3 radar chart data update doesn't work

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to draw a D3 radar chart where the user can select a dropdown menu option and the data will update.  However, the first one that is selected is drawn, but after that if I select anything else the data doesn't update.  The code is pasted below and I highlighted the problematic part:

```
var width = 700,
    height = 500,
    barHeight = height / 2 - 40;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#a50f15","#de2d26", "#fb6a4a","#fc9272", "#fcbba1"]);

var tickValues = [2,4,6,8,10];

var svg = d3.select('#radial').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");


  var data = pangolins[0];

  var numBars = data.data.length;

  var radius = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0,10])
      .range([0, barHeight]);

  var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("linear-closed")
    .radius(function(d) { return radius(d.count); })
    .angle(function(d,i) { return (i * 2 * Math.PI / numBars); });

  var area = d3.svg.area.radial()
    .interpolate(line.interpolate())
    .innerRadius(radius(0))
    .outerRadius(line.radius())
    .angle(line.angle());

  tickValues.sort(function(a,b) { return b - a; });

  var tickPath = svg.selectAll(".tickPath")
      .data(tickValues).enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("class", "tickPath")
      .attr("d", function(d) { 
        var tickArray = [];
        for (i=0;i<numBars;i++) tickArray.push({count : d});
        return area(tickArray); 
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
      .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return (i === 0) ? "black" : "white"; })
      .style("stroke-width", function(d,i) { return (i === 0) ? "1px" : ".5px"; });

  var lines = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(data.data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class","lines");

  lines.append("line")
    .attr("y2", - barHeight )
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width",".5px")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + (i * 360 / numBars) + ")"; });

  lines.append("text")
    .attr("class", "names")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return (barHeight + 15) * Math.sin((i * 2 * Math.PI / numBars)); })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return -(barHeight + 15) * Math.cos((i * 2 * Math.PI / numBars)); })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d,i) { 
    if (i===0 || i===numBars/2) {
        return "middle";
      }else if (i <= numBars/2) {
        return "begin";
      }else {
        return "end";
      }
    })
    .style("font-weight","bold")
    .text(function(d) { return d.threat; });







$('#pangolinSelect').change(function() {
        var selected = $( "#pangolinSelect option:selected" ).text();
        console.log(selected);
        var selected_d;
        pangolins.forEach(function(d){
            if(selected ==d.id){
                selected_d = d;
            }
        });
        console.log("selected_d");
        console.log(selected_d);
        changePangolin(selected_d);

    });

// changePangolin(data);
```

//PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! // 
   //PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! // 
   //PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! //

```
function changePangolin(newdata) {

    console.log('change pangolin');
    console.log(newdata);

  var t = d3.transition()
      .duration(750);

  // JOIN new data with old elements.
  var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data([newdata])
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .transition(t)
    .attr("d", function(d) { console.log(d); return area(d.data); })
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px");


}
```

Here is a screenshot of the initial select that works, but then the area stays the same when another option is selected:
[image]

below is a sample dataset:

```
var pangolins = [{
    "id": "Philippine Pangolin", 
    "idd":"PhilippinePangolin",
    "description": "",
    "status": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "threat": "Local Hunting / Domestic Trade", 
            "note": "Meat + Scales + Skin",
            "count": 7
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "International Trade", 
            "note": "Meat + Scales + Skin + Whole Animal",
            "count": 7
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "Habitat Loss", 
            "count": 5
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "Pesticide use", 
            "count": 0
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "Deforestation", 
            "count": 4
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "Road Kill", 
            "count": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "Sunda Pangolin", 
    "idd":"SundaPangolin",
    "description": "",
    "status": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "threat": "Local Hunting / Domestic Trade", 
            "count": 3
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "International Trade", 
            "note": "Meat + Scales + Skin + Whole Animal",
            "count": 10
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "Habitat Loss", 
            "count": 7
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "Pesticide use", 
            "count": 0
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "Deforestation", 
            "count": 4
        }, 
        {
            "threat": "Road Kill", 
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Description seems good, but help us help you by putting this together in a **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is this line:

```
 var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
```

The first time you run `changePangolin` there is no element with a class `layer`, and the path is appended as expected. However, from the second time on, as there is already an element with a class named "layer" in the DOM, your "enter" selection will be always empty.

**Solution**:

Append your path outside the `changePangolin` function:

```
var layer = svg.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px");;
```

And, inside `changePangolin`, simply change it:

```
layer.transition(t)
    .attr("d", area(newdata.data))
```